# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /templates/section-home.php on Line 34

Tags: php

I have changed my php version from 5.6 to 7.2.

> **Warning**: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /templates/section-home.php on Line 34

This is the line

```
 for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++) { if ( px_opt('home-gallery-'.$j) ) { $slideCount+=1;  $slideNumber=$j;} }
```

In this code

```
    <?php
            $slideCount = "";
            $slideNumber= "";
            if ( px_opt('home-type-switch') == 'home-slider' ) {
              for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++) { if ( px_opt('home-gallery-'.$j) ) { $slideCount+=1;  $slideNumber=$j;} }
                if ( $slideCount > 1 ) { ?>
```

What do I have to change?
Thank you

Comment: Ummmmm, and line #34 is where exactly?

Comment: For future reference, it is always usful to identify the LINE with the error. Specially if its line 34 and you only show us 8 lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to initialize your $slideCount and $slideNumber variables as 0 instead of ""